# mod_rewrite for codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Has anybody in the history of the internet and web development, been able to get rid of the "index.php" with mod_rewrite in codeIgniter.

I've been trying for several days now and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have your .htaccess file in the wrong place. CodeIgniter has a default .htaccess placed in the applications folder, which I mistakenly took for the one I should edit.

You actually need to create a new .htaccess under the root folder. So not code_igniter/applications/.htacces...but code_igniter/.htaccess

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this one (in .htaccess file):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Not sure where I got it but it works for my codeigniter install, local and live. Don't forget to set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in your config file.

Comment: i tried this solution sand it didn't work. Is it still your current configuration? thanks

Comment: I guess double check the location of your system and application files. I think this rewrite assumes they are in the web root - haven't looked at it in ages though.

Comment: Using MacOSX Mavericks
setup the server and add this httpd.conf rule

Remember we osx unix users must write
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>

instead of
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Answer (score 3):

For mod_rewrite use the following in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If your codeigniter instance is running in a subdirectory then use the rewrite base command before the RewriteRule

```
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
```

Then set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In the config file.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I already tried everything in the user guide and the codeIgniter wiki pages. None of it has worked os far.  
My instance of codeIgniter is running in the root(http://localhost), no subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I configured it under Linux using the instructions from [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/). However, I configured it via `httpd.conf` instead of using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that gives me some hope. I'm trying to set it up on my Mac running MAMP.
I tried the httpd.conf already and blew the whole thing up.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the settings provided above and they always worked - unless I did not have mod_rewrite enabled.

If you are having issues check to ensure you have mod_rewrite enabled. If you do not it will not matter what you put into .htacess or your Apache config